# How can I create a expandable list, how it is in my image?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to create a clear list view in SwiftUI, like in my picture:

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried a lot of things, but I always end up with a normal clear list.

It should look similar to the program "notion", which also has a "toggle list".

```
struct Bookmark: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let icon: String
    var items: [Bookmark]?

    // some example websites
    static let apple = Bookmark(name: "1", icon: "1.circle")
    static let bbc = Bookmark(name: "2", icon: "square.and.pencil")

    // some example groups
    static let example1 = Bookmark(name: "September", icon: "star", items: [Bookmark.1, Bookmark.2])
    static let example2 = Bookmark(name: "2023", icon: "timer", items: [Bookmark.1, Bookmark.2])
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let items: [Bookmark] = [.example1, .example2]

    var body: some View {
        List(items, children: \.items) { row in
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: row.icon)
                Text(row.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Plese provide some code which illustrates the issue as a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @BenzyNeez 

‚‘struct Bookmark: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let icon: String
    var items: [Bookmark]?

    // some example websites
    static let apple = Bookmark(name: „1“, icon: "1.circle")
    static let bbc = Bookmark(name: „2“, icon: "square.and.pencil")

    // some example groups
    static let example1 = Bookmark(name: „Se“ptember, icon: "star", items: [Bookmark.1, Bookmark.2)
    static let example2 = Bookmark(name: „2023“, icon: "timer", items: [Bookmark.1, Bookmark.2)

}'

Comment: @JojoWho please [edit] your question with additional info, don’t put it in the comments. See also [ask].

Comment: your code works for me when I replace `items: [Bookmark.1, Bookmark.2]` with `items: [.apple, .bbc]`.
 I don't know what "notion" is or look like, can you show a picture.
 You write,
 `I'm trying to create a clear list view in SwiftUI` **and then** `...I always end up with a normal clear list.`, 
do you want a clear list or not? If not what color do you want the list to have?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine
Unfortunately, I made a mistake and the notion actually looks exactly like the picture I have already inserted.
I would like a expandable list

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, to have your two lists side-by-side and individually expandable, as shown in your picture.

Note you could also try using a two columns Grid.

```
struct Bookmark: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let icon: String
    var items: [Bookmark]?

    // some example websites
    static let apple = Bookmark(name: "1", icon: "1.circle")
    static let bbc = Bookmark(name: "2", icon: "square.and.pencil")

    // some example groups
    static let example1 = Bookmark(name: "September", icon: "star", items: [.apple, .bbc])
    static let example2 = Bookmark(name: "2023", icon: "timer", items: [.apple, .bbc])
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let items: [Bookmark] = [.example1, .example2]

    var body: some View {
        HStack (spacing: 1){
            ForEach(items) { item in
                List([item], children: \.items) { row in
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: row.icon)
                        Text(row.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```